# Struts 2 format money rounding off

Tags: java, struts2, format, currency

I used `<s:text name="format.money">` tag to format a BigDecimal value of 4.74500000.

The result was $4.74 but I was expecting $4.75.

Why is this the case? How does Struts deal with the formatting? Because when I formatted 57.625090, it showed to be $57.63 which was correct.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://struts.apache.org/docs/formatting-dates-and-numbers.html), `money.format` uses `DecimalFormat` with a pattern of `##0.00` to format numbers. Namely, round to closest number with only two fractional digits, with ties being rounded to the [even neighbor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_HALF_EVEN).

This is consistent with your results.